# Calling linear to converted dB bands and creating few more bands such as VV/VH, VH/VV, VV+VH in function using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-1

My question is similar to:

- [Radar Vegetation Index Using Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/434806/radar-vegetation-index-using-google-earth-engine)
- [Convert Sentinel-1 images data from dB to linear](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/424225/convert-sentinel-1-images-data-from-db-to-linear)

I am new to GEE and JavaScript.

I want to create the following number of bands for each Sentinel1 scene other than original bands (vv,vh in linear scale).

1. RVI, NRPB, VV-db, VH-db, VV/VH (db), VH/VV(db), VV+VH (db).

```
//// RVI calculation
var RVI = vvVhIw.map(function (image){
  var rvi = image.expression('sqrt((vv)/(vv+vh)) *  ((4*(vh))/(vv+vh))',
    {'vv': image.select('VV'),
     'vh': image.select('VH')
    }
    );
    return rvi;
  });

// calculate NRPB Band
var NRPB = vvVhIw.map(function (image){
  var nrpb = image.expression('(vv-vh)/(vv+vh)',
    {'vv': image.select('VV'),
     'vh': image.select('VH')
    }
    );
    return nrpb;
  });
  

// convert Linear to DB
var TO_DB = vvVhIw.map(function (image){
  var to_db = image.expression('10 * log10(linear)',
    {linear: image.select(['VV','VH']),
    }
    );
    return to_db;
  });
```

How to call the VV and VH bands that are in decibel in a function to create bands such as VV/VH (db), VH/VV (db), VV+VH (db). At the end, I will have 7 bands for each Sen1 image.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you might want to start off your processing in linear, and convert to dB in the last step. For that, use `COPERNICUS/S1_GRD_FLOAT`. Otherwise, you convert with this:

```
ee.Image(10).pow(db.divide(10))
```

Inspect a pixel in this script to verify that the collections and conversions looks as expected.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8c613c15465708757872505d0ca9c937

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will update you once I finish it.